# Tool for dropdown

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am creating tool for dropdownlist using

```
For each item as Listitem in Dropdown1.items
  item.attributes.add("title",item.text)
Next
```

How can convert this to linq ?

Thanks,

Comment: why do you want to? Since you have a side effect - you are modifying `items` - you really shouldn't

Comment: when the item width increase the dropdown width, user needs a tooltip

Comment: Yes, but why do you want to "convert this to LINQ" ? the Q in LINQ stands for **Query** - you're not querying anything here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownList1.Items.OfType<ListItem>().ToList().ForEach(item => item.Attributes.Add("title", item.Text));`

Comment: So far as this is just a kind of perversion that's no matter :) Really, don't use that. Variant with foreach loop looks more readable.